# Percentile function to calculate cumulative in spotfire

Tags: excel, spotfire, percentile

hope you  are doing well. It would be great if you can help me out with teh following challenge I am facing in spotfire:

In excel I have calculate the market share by using the "percentile" formula along with a cumulative share column, this gives the total "cumulative_share" under 5%, total "cumulative_share" under 8% and so on..:

Here's the image:

[image]

When I try to replicate the same in Spotfire, I am not able to get similar results:

Here's the image:

[image]

Here the "precentile" column in sport fire is same as the column "H" from Excel.

Please help me understand how to achieve this

Comment: Maybe not appropriate but why do you need to recalculate it? It seems that you could just import the file into Spotfire rather than recalculating it.